# How to match a e-mail from a table with dax function USERPRINCIPALNAME and let the user visualize the report in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to hide a page from a group of users, but I've read that there is no RLS-like service to do that. I found a "tip" to use a card and paint it white or transparent to hide the page contents. It would work fine for me, but here is my problem:

I have a table with page name and the e-mail of the users allowed to access its contents. I need to query that table, returning the page name when the e-mail equals to USERPRINCIPALNAME (DAX function), but I haven't found how to link these information.

I tried to create a column named "allowed", comparing the e-mail value with this DAX function, but PowerBI does not allow its use (it can only be used with Measures). Then, I tried to create a measure comparing both values, but I cannot access the table value (it's not displayed in the list of available options).

What can I do? Any clues?

Regards

Comment: Power BI does support RLS.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact RLS feature with Power BI that can be used to restrict data access for given users.
Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls